# Python 3.x - How to update a CSV file on Google Drive with requests patch

Tags: python-3.x, csv, python-requests

I am trying to update a .CSV file stored in a Google Drive folder with requests.patch(). The request succeeds and the file gets updated, but when I open it I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17VSA.png).

I don't understand why 'Content-Disposition', 'Content-Type', etc. are added to my file. Is there any way I could update the .CSV without them?

My code:

```
headers = {'Authorization': token}
para = {'parents': 'folder_id'}
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': open('file.csv', 'rb')
}
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/'+file_id+'?uploadType=media'

r=requests.patch(url, headers = headers, files = files)
print(r.text)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the request body is the multipart upload. So how about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/'+file_id+'?uploadType=media'
```

#### To:

```
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/'+file_id+'?uploadType=multipart'
```

#### Reference:

- [Performing a Multipart Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/multipart-upload)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

### Added:

When you want to move the folder of the file, please modify as follows. `para = {'parents': 'folder_id'}` is not used in this case.

#### To:

```
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/'+file_id+'?uploadType=multipart&addParents=### new folderId ###&removeParents=### current folderId ###'
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

Comment: Silly me, that was pretty straightforward to fix. Thank you!

Comment: @Nom I'm glad your issue was solved. I had forgot about the update of the folder. So I added it. Could you please confirm it?